# Only the last added item gets printed

Tags: java

```
List < Response > Data = new ArrayList < Response > ();
Response object = null;

JSONObject documentRoot = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray documentChild = documentRoot.getJSONArray("Main");
JSONArray allergyArray = null;
JSONArray vitalsArray = null;

for (int i = 0; i < documentChild.length(); i++) {
    child = documentChild.getJSONObject(i);
    if (Condition1) {
        allergyArray = child.getJSONArray("Allergy");
    } else if {
        vitalsArray = child.getJSONArray("Vitals");
    }
}

object = new Response(); // POJO class

if (null != allergyArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < allergyArray.length(); i++) {
        object.setCap(allergyArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Cap"));
        object.setRea(allergyArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Rea"));
    }
}

if (null != vitalsArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vitalsArray.length(); i++) {
        object.setName(vitalsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
        object.setMedic(vitalsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Medic"));
    }
}

Data.add(object);
```

Only the last added item gets printed, when i try to iterate and print the result.

```
public void onLoadComplete(List < Response > item) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("Get", item.get(i).getCap()); // I get only the last item which is added.
    }      
}
```

Why is my List Object passed to onLoadComplete function contains only the last item added to the POJO class.

Comment: Java is OO, not procedural like PHP. You need to create a new `Response` instance everytime instead of reusing the same one.

Comment: @BalusC: i tried creating new instance in the corresponding for-loops... object = new Response();

Comment: You have to create the new `Response` and then call `Data.add(object);`, all inside the `for` loop.

Comment: If the JSON library is from www.json.org, then `getJSONArray` never returns `null`. See http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String) and http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONArray(int) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loops, you set the values (cap, rea, name & medic) on the same object in each iteration, it means that only the last value will be set after the iterations are completed.

For each value you need to create a new object. This is a basic example, some checks are need to be added for safety:

```
if (null != allergyArray && null != vitalsArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allergyArray.length() && i < vitalsArray.length(); ++i)
    {
        object = new Response(); // POJO class
        object.setCap(allergyArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Cap"));
        object.setRea(allergyArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Rea"));
        object.setName(vitalsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
        object.setMedic(vitalsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Medic"));

        Data.add(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't need to combine these loops into one right.... i mean i can still have it separate and create new instances in each of their loops...

Comment: I assumed that the data is related, but if the lists are used to create separate objects, just create objects in side the loops and store them in `Data`

Comment: One final question, i did not understand your previous comment.... its a single List object which i am going to pass to the function.

Comment: If you want to populate the array with objects from `allergyArray` and from `vitalsArray` separately, then you should do it in two for loops, if you construct objects that are based on both arrays, you need to perform it in one loop.